# Is there a way to measure uniformness of points in a 2D square?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, uniform-distribution

Questions : Say I have 1000 points, that are distributed in a $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ square. It is not uniformly distributed. For example I might have "clusters" of points within the square, and conversely, there may be some empty patches of space within the square. I want to get a measure of uniformness in the distribution of the points. But, I don't think it can be the $\chi^2$ test for a uniform distribution for what I want to do. The measure should be continuous with respect to the point locations.

Context: I have a dataset of variables, that are closely linked to the interaction positions within a $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ square. I do not know those points a priori, but I do know that when I map those variables to the points in the square, it has to be somewhat uniformly distributed. (It should look as if they were sampled from a 2d uniform distribution.)

I want to learn the mapping between the variables and the point locations, so I am trying to setup a neural network model that can learn to map those variables. Loss function will be a measure of uniformness, so that if the learned mapping does not give a uniformly distribution of points, it will be penalized and the model will be corrected (through backpropagation). Now I've been thinking about what could be used for such measure of uniformness. With some Google search, I learned that the $\chi^2$ test can be used to measure the uniformness of points, but I don't think it can be used for the neural network, because the method is based on dividing the square into many small squares, and  counting the number of points in each small squares. The problem is, the gradient cannot be calculated, because an infinitismal change in the point locations won't change the $\chi^2$ test results. So there is no gradient and the model cannot be trained.

So I need a measure of uniformness, with which I can calculate the gradient w.r.t. point locations. So it has to be a continuous measure. Does anyone know of such a measure? Thank you.

Comment: One commonly used measure of distance between two distributions is the Earth Movers' Distance, also known as the [tag:wasserstein] metric. Unfortunately, I do not believe it has a closed form expression, so you would need to numerically approximate the gradient you are looking for, which could be a performance problem.

Comment: You have a slight issue, in that a random sample from a 2d uniform distribution will usually be visually clumpier than a manually uniform distribution across the square.  So for example if you divided your big square into 100 little squares, the distribution of the number in a particular little square would have a binomial distribution Bin(1000,0.01), approximately a Poisson(10) distribution, and you would have to decide whether you want to see this as uniform or whether you regarded exactly 10 in each square as uniform

Comment: There are many such measures, and they give different results. This underlies a bigger issue of unsupervised learning -- once you get some clustering, how do you know it's good? For your results to be meaningful, you have to tie it to an application. This will in turn inform the correct measure of uniformity to use.

Comment: @Henry Sure, if it is uniform random it won't look as uniform as manual uniform distribution. But I want is a distribution "which looks like it is from a 2D uniform random distribution" so I wouldn't mind a bit of clumping.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks for the input. I omitted some details here. There is an analytical method to map the variables to the points, and I am going to include in my loss function the distance between the point locations found from the neural net and the analytical method. So that the analytically found points will somehow anchor those points that NN found. The point distribution from the analytical method is not quite uniform random, so I am hoping to "disperse" those points with the NN approach, while keeping them somewhat close to analytical point locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends on the possible alternatives to uniformity you need to measure.

One attractive approach that immediately yields several solutions is to use a measure of the distance between the empirical copula and the independence copula (which describes the uniform distribution on the unit square). For instance, you might use the $L^2$ norm of the difference between the copulae.  See the code at the end of this post for details.

Here are the results of a simulation study of the distribution of this norm when $n=100$ points are created with *iid* Beta$(1,\beta)$ coordinates. When $\beta=1$ this is uniform and as $\beta$ increases the points start favoring locations near the origin.

[image]

The first row plots the Beta density functions.  The second row plots sample data.  The third row plots the distribution of 500 values of this norm from 500 independent sets of sample data.

The distribution for $\beta=1.5$ is clearly separated from the distribution for $\beta=1,$ showing this approach has high power to discriminate the third or fourth columns from the left column.

A subtler way in which a distribution might fail to be uniform is by local clustering (or anticlustering).  To explore that, I created uniform samples of the square and snapped the results to a grid of $h+1$ equally spaced values.

[image]

This method has only a little power to distinguish $h=10$ from no clustering with $n=100$ points, but is very powerful at identifying the $h=5$ clustering at the right.

Because you are interested in datasets with about $n=1000$ points, here is a similar study for simulated data of that size.  It exhibits reasonable power to distinguish the middle plot ($\beta=1.05$) from uniformity and high power to distinguish the right plot ($\beta=1.1$).  I cannot visually discern any difference in uniformity among these cases, suggesting the $L^2$ norm works well.

[image]

---

If you are concerned about identifying local clustering, instead use a local measure of non-uniformity, such as the mean nearest-neighbor distance or (edge-adjusted) mean numbers of neighbors within a moving window of fixed size.

---

This `R` code snippet simulates an array of points in the unit square and (using a $O(n^2)$ brute force algorithm) computes the $L^2$ distance to the independence copula.

```R
uv <- matrix(runif(2*n), 2)       # Coordinates in columns
y <- apply(uv, 2, function(xy) {
  z <- uv - xy                    # Vector between `xy` and a point
  mean(z[1,] <= 0 & z[2,] <= 0)   # Value of the copula at `xy`
})
sqrt(mean((uv[1,]*uv[2,] - y)^2)) # L^2 distance between the reference and the copula
```

A more efficient method to compute the empirical copula would use a lexicographic sort on the coordinates or an equivalent efficient spatial search structure (e.g., a quadtree).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I am not very knowledgable in the terms like empirical copula and the independence copula, so I'll look into it and get back to you.

Comment: The meanings of those terms are explained in the code snippet.  For the concepts, searching our site should provide some useful information.